# Predictive text in Richtextbox in vb

Tags: vb.net, richtextbox, t9

I have almost finished with my text editor in Visual basic.. And the last thing I want to add in my project is a *sub* which will show a Drop-Down menu each time the user adds a letter(character) in the richtextbox..For example when the user types *a* in the richtextbox, the program will show a Drop-Down menu with all words whose first letter is *a*.. Then if user types *b* after a then the Drop-Down menu will have all words whose first two letters are *ab*..The Drop-Down menu will get its words from a text file in that path: *C:/Desktop/txtfile.txt*

Comment: Hopes and dreams are very nice. Unfortunately, they are not valid inputs in SO. Please, try something by your own, share it with us and ask about specific problems.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [TextBox.AutoCompleteMode Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.textbox.autocompletemode?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8) to suggest or append the Predictive text in the textbox or richtextbox.

[image]
<sub>(source: [net-informations.com](http://net-informations.com/q/faq/img/autocomplete.png))</sub>

The following VB.Net program add some string values to AutoCompleteStringCollection and display as Autocomplete TextBox while entering text:

```vb
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        TextBox1.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Suggest
        TextBox1.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource

        ' You can read the custom source file
        ' for example: File.ReadAllLine("C://Desktop//txtfile.txt")
        Dim DataCollection As New AutoCompleteStringCollection()

        addItems(DataCollection)
        TextBox1.AutoCompleteCustomSource = DataCollection
    End Sub
    Public Sub addItems(ByVal col As AutoCompleteStringCollection)            
        col.Add("Abel")
        col.Add("Bing")
        col.Add("Catherine")
        col.Add("Varghese")
        col.Add("John")
        col.Add("Kerry")
    End Sub
End Class
```

[Reference Here](http://net-informations.com/q/faq/autocomplete.html)

Comment: Thank's that's cool!